# Why would SqlBulkCopy be extremely slow sometimes?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sqlbulkcopy

I'm trying to diagnose a performance issue with SqlBulkCopy.

I have a point in my code where most of the time, one row is being inserted, but sometimes hundreds of rows can be inserted, most of the time it runs fine and completes in less than a second even for the large cases, but occasionally this code takes 10 seconds to insert a single row, and we suspect it's timing out on our test environment where the server is under heavy load (90%+ cpu usage) causing tests to randomly fail.

I can't imagine what would cause the bulk insert to take 10 sec to insert a single row, how should I approach to diagnose what's causing this?

```
Using bulk As New SqlBulkCopy(CType(Me._connection, SqlConnection), SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, trans)
    bulk.BulkCopyTimeout = Me.commandTimeout
    For Each column As DataColumn In insertTable.Columns
        bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ColumnName, column.ColumnName)
    Next
    bulk.DestinationTableName = destinationTable

    bulk.WriteToServer(insertTable)
    Dim statistics = CType(_connection, SqlConnection).RetrieveStatistics()
End Using
```

These are the statistics I get from RetrieveStatistics:

[image: Results from RetrieveStatistics]

Comment: You would need to check what the query executing is waiting on and what locks are on the table being inserted into

Comment: Is there a way to check that? I doubt there will be any locks though because there's only a single thread running during my local test.

Comment: There are many resources that can show that info - other than querying the system DMVs  you can look at the sp_blitz tools or sp_whoIsActive among others

Comment: Session wait stats are an easy way to see what that session was waiting on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-session-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16